# How can I grow a pineapple plant from a store-bought pineapple?

Tags: planting

I've read in several places that a pineapple plant can be grown from the top of a store-bought pineapple, provided it has a crown/leaves intact.

The only problem is that I'm finding many contradictions in the exact method to do so.

- This [method](http://www.gardeningtipsnideas.com/2006/11/how_to_grow_a_pineapple_from_its_top.html) instructs to remove all fruit from the plant and
  waiting for the crown to root sideways in soil, before planting it upright.
- This [method](http://www.rickswoodshopcreations.com/Pineapple/pineapple.htm) recommends removing all fruit and rooting in a glass
  of water.
- This [method](http://www.tropicalpermaculture.com/growing-pineapples.html) says to remove all fruit, but **don't** put the
  crown in water. Just plant it vertically in the soil.
- This [method](http://www.plantea.com/pineapple-houseplant.htm) recommends keeping the top inch or so of fruit
  attached to the crown.

Does anyone have any first-hand experience using any of these methods? I'd prefer one of the last two, since they seem easiest, but I don't want to take any shortcuts if they will end up not working at all.

Comment: Do you live in Hardiness Zone 6b?

Comment: 7a actually [15 chars]

Comment: If [Purdue (Indiana) University](http://www.ag.purdue.edu/) have their information correct: [Climate](http://www.hort.purdue.edu/newcrop/morton/pineapple.html#Climate) -- I think you're climate is against you, unless of course you plan to grow in something like a (heated) greenhouse...

Comment: @Mike they're often grown from fruit tops in theUK - but as a pot plant. sort of novelty like growing carrot tops!

Comment: @winwaed if "Doresoom" wishes to grow as a "novelty" (indoor potted plant) then I totally agree it's a completely different (easier) gardening challenge...

Comment: I was planning on planting it in a pot and bringing it inside during the winter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm in the UK and, some years ago, grew a pineapple plant *indoors* (as a "novelty" - it never fruited). I used the third method you mention, based on the advice given in [The Pip Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1906251444) by Keith Mossman:

- Make up or buy some really free-draining compost (I used a soil-less seed and cutting compost to which I added a little coarse sand)
- Cut off the top of the pineapple with a disc of flesh about half an inch thick
- Leave the crown for about 48 hours with the cut surface uppermost to dry out
- Choose a pot with a diameter that will leave a couple of inches to spare all round the crown to facilitate watering; it doesn't have to be very deep, but good drainage is vital, so I would place a layer of crocks or pebbles at the bottom
- Plant the crown so that it is just covered but not buried deeply, making sure that the tuft of leaves is well clear of the compost
- Water gently (always use tepid water) and place the pot either in a clear polythene bag and stand it in a warm, light place (perhaps close to a storage heater), or in a heated propagator, if you have one. *Consistent warmth*  (ideally bottom heat, 70 to 80 degrees F/ 21 to 27C) is essential to get the crown to root.
- Keep the compost slightly damp to the touch *but not wet*
- When new leaves show that it is rooting, keep it in its warm, light spot until there is enough growth to indicate that it is established, and then move it to a permanent home in the warmest and lightest spot you can find; it prefers a winter temperature of about 65F/ 18C and a summer one rising to 90F/ 32C.

Answer (score 7):

I grew a pineapple indoors, leaving about an inch or two of fruit, and simply placing that on potting soil in a pot, right after cutting.  I watered by pouring water on the top of the plant in the middle.  The plant appeared to thrive, getting very big and wide.  After several years, I did get a baby pinapple, which smelled wonderful but was rather tart when I ate it.

If you live where it can freeze and have it outdoors in the summer, be very careful to bring it in before even the first mildest frost.  They don't like that at all.